# Cassandra: can you use a derived value from a column as part of the partition key?

Tags: cassandra

Let's say I have a table schema that has a timestamp for the event:

```
CREATE TABLE event_bucket_1 (
  event_source text,
  event_year int,
  event_month int,
  event_id text,
  event_time timestamp,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ((event_source, event_year, event_month), event_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_id DESC)
```

My question is: Can I skip adding the `event_year` and `event_month` columns and replace it with some kind of function like `year(event_time)` and `month(event_time)`? The thinking is that `event_year`, `event_month` are both duplication of information from `event_time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the partition key needs to be static, and AFAIK, can't be evaluated at.

You can try to open a ticket as an improvement for future versions at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Seems to be a good use case and would fit more scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. But, from my understanding, you want to query based on year and month, right? You can accomplish this by replacing the `event_year` and `event_month` by `event_time` in your compound key and use query time ranges:

> SELECT * FROM event_bucket_1 where event_source='source' and event_time > '2018-06-01 00:00:00' and event_time < '2018-07-01 00:00:00';

Comment: I think this only applies to clustering key, not partition key. I need the `year`, `month` in there to limit the size of my partitions.